# Straight line , gre prolem $170$ score hard

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

What is the distance between the two straight line represented by the equation

$3x+4y=10$ and $6x+8y=10?$ $$A>1$$ $$B>2$$ $$C>\frac43$$ $$D>\frac12$$ $$E>\frac52$$

I try to solve it , firstly find intercept of both line and then find mid point between of them ,and calculate distance between both line , suggest me where I m wrong

Comment: The minimum distance?

Comment: They do not intersect. The easiest way would be to solve for the y intercept and subtract the two

Comment: @Eoin: That doesn't work. You need the distance along a perpendicular, and the $y$-axis isn't a perpendicular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two lines intersect, then the distance between them is $0$. Otherwise they're parallel and have the same slope, which means the lines can be written as

$ax + by = c$      and
$ax + by = d$

The distance between the lines is then $$\frac{|c-d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

In your case the two lines are

$3x + 4y = 10$      and
$3x + 4y = 5$

so the distance between them is $\frac{|10-5|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** They are asking for the **shortest** distance between the two parallel lines (not the horizontal or vertical distance). Here's an outline for solving it:

- Find the slope (call it $m_1$) of both parallel lines (call them $L_1$ and $L_2$).
- Compute the slope (call it $m_2$) of a line perpendicular to both $L_1$ and $L_2$.
- Choose any point (call it $P$) that is on $L_1$.
- Construct the equation of the line (call it $L$) with slope $m_2$ that passes through $P$.
- Solve a system of equations to find $Q$, the point where $L$ and $L_2$ intersect.
- Use Pythagoras to compute the distance between $P$ and $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me call the lines $l1$ and $l2$, in which:

$l1: y=\frac{-3}{4}x+2.5$

and

$l2: y=\frac{-3}{4}x+1.25$.

With a little notice to the above lines we see that these are the lines mentioned in the question. In another language, we have made the above line equations by altering the **shape** of the line equations. As we see, both lines have the same slopes, and hence they are parallel to each other and **there is no intersection**. So we can define distance between them. Let me define $l3$ as:

$l3: y=\frac{4}{3}x$

As we see $l3$ is perpendicular to $l1$ and $l2$ (because the product of their slopes is equal to $-1$).  We wanna find the intersection of $l3$ with the both lines. So we have:

$y=\frac{4}{3}x\rightarrow\frac{4}{3}x=\frac{-3}{4}x+2.5\rightarrow x=\frac{30}{25}\rightarrow y=\frac{40}{25}\rightarrow P1=(\frac{30}{25},\frac{40}{25})$

$y=\frac{4}{3}x\rightarrow\frac{4}{3}x=\frac{-3}{4}x+1.25\rightarrow x=\frac{15}{25}\rightarrow y=\frac{20}{25}\rightarrow P2=(\frac{15}{25},\frac{20}{25})$

In which $P1$ and $P2$ are the intersection of $l3$ with $l1$ and $l2$ respectively. The distance between $P1$ and $P2$ is the distance between $l1$ and $l2$, so we have:

$d_{l1,l2}=\sqrt{(\frac{30}{25}-\frac{15}{25})^2+(\frac{40}{25}-\frac{20}{25})^2}=\sqrt{(\frac{15}{25})^2+(\frac{20}{25})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{625}{625}}=1 $

Answer (score -1):

Since these two lines are parallel lines $( m_{1}=m_{2})$ they would never meet.But their interceptions of Y axis is the constant distance they would maintain.

Just measure that distance $$C_{1}-C_{2} = 2.5-1.25= 1.25 $$
So the ans choice is $A ,>1$.
its not greater than $1.5,1.33,2$ or $2.5$.$(B,C,E)$ though it is greater than $0.5 (1/2)$.